# exxcel formula to count running duplicates in row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duplicates, countif

Dears,

i want to count running duplicates in my excel for an upload. the target data should be as below:

```
1021023 0
1021023 1
1021023 2
1021034 0
1021034 1
1021039 0
1021039 1
1021039 2
```

Comment: i have achieved the following using the formula: =COUNTIF($A$4:$A69, A69)

1021023 1
1021023 2
1021023 3
1021034 1
1021034 2
1021039 1
1021039 2
1021039 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter 0.  In **B2** enter:

```
=IF(A2=A1,B1+1,0)
```

and copy down:

[image]

Comment: hi thanks for the reply. but this formula does not resolve the issue. the below is the output:
![]
1021023 0 1
1021023 0 1
1021023 0 0
1021034 0 1
1021034 0 1
1021039 0 0
1021039 0 1
1021039 0 0

Comment: I have tried @Gary's student formula and it provides exactly the answer you show in your target data above.

Comment: Hi,
the issue was resolved with @Gary's solution. Earlier i placed the 0 in other column.
thanks Gary